# Traversing with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-traversing

I have a function that adds a new unordered list item.  I'd like to set one of the element's values in the newly created list item to a value that is based on a value in the list item just above the new one.

For instance, if I have something like:

```
<form id="form" action="">

<ul id="list1" class="listing">

    <li id="input1" class="item">

        <input id="descr1" class="descr" type="text" value="" name="descr1" />
        <input id="group1" class="group" type="text" value="" name="group1" />
        <input id="order1" class="order_field" type="text" value="4" name="order1" />
        <input id="row1" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" name="select_row1" />

    </li>

    <li id="input2" class="item">

        <input id="descr2" class="descr" type="text" value="" name="descr2" />
        <input id="group2" class="group" type="text" value="" name="group2" />
        <input id="order2" class="order_field" type="text" value="5" name="order2" />
        <input id="row2" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2" name="select_row2" />

    </li>

</ul>
```

If I run the function that creates a new list item, I want the value in #order2 to be incremented by 1 and then the new list item (that will now have #order3) will be set to 6.  For example, after I have created the new list item it would look like this:

```
    <li id="input3" class="item">

        <input id="descr3" class="descr" type="text" value="" name="descr3" />
        <input id="group3" class="group" type="text" value="" name="group3" />
        <input id="order3" class="order_field" type="text" value="6" name="order3" />
        <input id="row3" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="3" name="select_row3" />

    </li>
```

I need to find a way to get to the last list item and get the value for the class .order_field and then use that value (+1) when I create the new list item.  My issue is I'm not sure how to put together the selector for getting to the last list item's .order_field value.

I hope that makes sense.

Thanks,
Shawn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply:

```
var value = $('#list1 li:last .order_field').val();
```

You also have to convert the value to a number, which you can do using `parseInt` or unary `+`:

```
var newValue = parseInt(value, 10) + 1;
// or
var newValue = +value + 1;
```

Comment: I got a lot of great responses to this question.  I really appreciate it.  I went with this one as it seemed a little cleaner and 'readable' within my code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var newValue = parseFloat($("#list1 li:last").children(".order_field").val())+1;
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/JBhdF/2/

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I appreciate you taking the time.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#list1 li:last input.order_field").val()
```

should give you the value that you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the last value with this:

```
var last_value = $("#list1 li:last").find(".order_field").val();
```

What does it do?
- Selects the last `li` inside `#list1` ul.
- Inside it, finds the element with class `order_field` and returns its value.

To increment it, just do:

```
var new_value = parseInt(last_value, 10) + 1;
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I appreciate the explanation.